# How to construct sentences about reunion

Tags: sentence-choice

I went to the high school reunion for the first time and met my old friends. When I describe this event using time expression, what sentences are appropriate?

> 1) It was the first meeting since the graduation.
>   2) I've seen them for the first time in 20 years / in a long time.
>   3) I saw them after 20 years / a long time.
>   4) It's been a long time to see them.

I always wonder which sentence is the most appropriate grammarwise and also sounds natural. Could you help me?

Comment: Personally, I think I might say this, "It was the first time we met since we graduated."

Comment: It was my first time seeing them since our graduation 20 years earlier.

Comment: I hadn't seen them since our graduation, 20 years ago.

Comment: I've had this question for long and did research myself.Personally,1) and 3) are easy to say and make sense grammatically. As for 3), I thought the question I asked before might be applied here, also.

Comment: continued,  The question I asked before "Is it possible to use present perfect instead of past perfect?"June6,2013.

Comment: Continued.  as for question 4)  I found the similar question on one site, in Japanese, and a teacher gave this sentence.  I have some doubts about this but it was answered by a teacher, So I thought it might work.   I was very confused and asked here.

Comment: I appreciate all the answered here.  They solved my questions.  But it is difficult for me to choose the best answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at each sentence in turn:

1)

> It was the first meeting since the graduation.

This is OK grammatically, but it is a little impersonal. Suggested alternatives:

> It was our first meeting since graduation.
>   It was our first meeting since we graduated.
>   It was the first time we met since we graduated.

2)

> 2) I've seen them for the first time in 20 years / in a long time.

This is perhaps the most interesting (and problematic) of your choices since present perfect doesn't really work here. Viable alternatives:

> I saw them for the first time in 20 years.
>   It was the first time I'd seen them in 20 years.
>   It's the first time I've seen them in 20 years.

3)

> I saw them after 20 years / a long time.

OK gramatically, but it sounds like you are recounting it years later. Could be something like:

> I hadn't seen them for 20 years.

4)

> It's been a long time to see them.

No. Should be something along the lines of:

> It's been a long time since I last saw them.
>   It had been a long time since I'd seen them.

... depending on what you are trying to say (and when the event you are talking about actually happened).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation for each sentence.  It is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I'd use any of your phrasings.  Here are some alternatives that came to mind:

> It was the first time I'd seen them in twenty years.
>
> I hadn't seen them in twenty years.
>
> It had been a long time since I'd last seen them.

I think I might say one of these instead.

Comment: My thoughts were in line with these. One other way to say it might be: _"It was **my** first time seeing them in twenty years."_

Comment: @J.R. I realized now that your sentence "my first time doing" is the easiest and simpliest way to say to me, because I don't have to think a lot about the tense.  I can just change the tense in the main be-verb.  It is very helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best one is:

> 3) I saw them after 20 years.

You could use "a long time" but I would prefer "20 years" which is more descriptive of the actual time period (unless dating yourself is a concern).

> 1) It was the first meeting since graduation.

is OK as an introductory statement, before getting into details about the reunion. Just "since graduation", not "since *the* graduation".

I would not use 2) because what you are describing is in the past and this is not using past tense. (The reunion has already ended).

And 4) is not in the past tense either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I change the tense in 2) and 4), like "I'd seen them for the first time in 20 years." and "It had been a long time to see them. Does it work?

Comment: @tennisgirl Then 2) is OK. For 3) I would say "It had been a long time since I had seen them." Infinitive "to see" does not really work here.